# Уничтожение объекта производного класса таким образом object->Release()

Tags: c++

В программе создаётся объект

```
IObject* object = myDevice->CreateObject(); //IObject абстрактный класс
```

Хочу уничтожать объект так `object-Release();` вместо `myDevice->RemoveObject();`

Правильно ли будет то что каждая переменная в классе потомке должна являться **указателем** и что при конструировании нужно выделять память вручную а при вызове функции Release() нужно просто так же вручную её освобождать?

Comment: Оба способа неправильные. Прочитайте лучше про умные указатели.

Comment: Я предпологаю использутся методология COM. Release уменьшает счётчик ссылок и уничтожает объект, если доходит до 0.

Comment: Вообще вопрос не дает понять что же вы используете? COM? Или самописное подобие COM?

Comment: от COM взято только имя функции

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Строго говоря в методе `release` можно просто написать `delete this;`. Но тут надо быть 100% уверенным в том что:

1. Объект создан при помощи `new`(не `new[]`, не placement `new`, это
   не локальный стэковый объект, не глобальный объект, не член класса)
2. Метод `release` будет вызван последним
3. Часть метода `release`после строки `delete this;` не оперирует
   никакими данными объекта.
4. Никто не будет использовать `this` никаким образом после `delete
   this;`(нельзя сравнивать `this` c `nullptr`, с другим указателем,
   выполнять приведения типов)

Если эти требования соблюдены, то всё будет работать как надо. Метод `release` будет делать именно то, что от него ожидается.

Хотя я бы так писать не стал. Во-первых потому что `delete this;` это опасная и некрасивая конструкция. Во-вторых вы "размазываете" однотипную функциональность на два класса. Созданием занимается `myDevice`, а уничтожением `object`. Не уверен на 100%, но мне кажется что тут нарушен принцип [High Cohesion](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP#5._.D0.92.D1.8B.D1.81.D0.BE.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B5_.D0.B7.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B5.D0.BF.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.28High_Cohesion.29.5B2.5D)(пусть меня поправят, если это не так)

Куда логичнее будет выглядеть такой подход:

```
IObject* object = myDevice->сreate();
//...
myDevice->release(object);
```

Или такой:

```
std::shared_ptr<IObject> object = myDevice->сreate();
```

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` всё же.

Comment: @alexolut, точно, спасибо. Привык что в qt-шным названиям :)